# Angular binding directive's parameters to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am having trouble binding directive's parameters (using isolated scope) to access them from the directive's custom controller.

Please check this fiddle (open the console, to see the logged results!) http://jsfiddle.net/xj9gqqxn/4/

```
<div ng-controller="appCtr">
  <div>
    <div custom-directive param="customer.name">
    <span>{{customer.name}}</span>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i log inside the directive's link function the value gets logged accordenly, but when i do the same within the constructor function of the controller i see the value as undefined.

If someone know how to access directive's parameters values within the constructor function of the directive's controller, please share the answer or point where i am making a mistake.. sad for me I got no further clues...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your controller has same scope as directive so this will work just fine:

```
app.controller('customController', ['$scope', '$timeout' , function($scope,$timeout) {
    console.log("[customController:new] -  param value is: " + $scope.param);
}])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pegla/xj9gqqxn/6/

Also if you are searching for bindToController so directive $scope value is bound to controller instead of $scope, you could do this:

```
bindToController: {
            param: '='
        },
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pegla/xj9gqqxn/8/

Comment: Thanks Pegia... that is a clever workaround in order to have the parameter value "at hand" inside the construction function of the directive... i will try this as soon i get to work, and if it works this will be the correct answer!!

Comment: I also realize that using bindTOController without an alias (via controllerAs or using the 'controller Identified as alias') is prone to bug

Comment: about above statement: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15088